# "can't setup device- couldn't install the admin app" Android Management API

Tags: android, android-management-api

Last year we've setup AMAPI with couple of devices. Recently we've got a new device, but when I tried to set it up I got `"can't setup device- couldn't install the admin app"`.

I've tried to:

- reset/restart the device many times
- generate a different policy
- wait a few days and retry ( I've read somewhere that it can be due to Google )
- setup an old device again ( this also failed )

I used the same code that worked once with the same service account.

Here's the response of the enrollmentToken:

```
{
    "name": "enterprises/LC01aymplz/enrollmentTokens/izqaqdWxscS7wDwMYIWeTm7k81rFtpVjv9nxgUhtw7k",
    "value": "QFXVLZHIWZMVBPLWFFRT",
    "duration": "7776000s",
    "expirationTimestamp": "2022-06-26T05:40:04.054Z",
    "policyName": "enterprises/LC01aymplz/policies/dh_ewelink",
    "qrCode": "{\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME\":\"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc/.receivers.CloudDeviceAdminReceiver\",\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM\":\"xx\",\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION\":\"https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup\",\"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE\":{\"com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.EXTRA_ENROLLMENT_TOKEN\":\"xx\"}}"
  }
```

Comment: I tried to create an enrollment token using sample policy and the device provisioning is successful.

To help you better, I would like to confirm the following:
- if you are using Android 6.0 devices or up.
- sample of the policy that you use.
- ensure that you have good network connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was that I've setup the AMAPI more than a year ago, and the API has changed.

I've **walked through the documentation** again and found out that:

- `contactInfo` on enterprise is required now, but then it was optional ( just patch the enterprise )
- `allowPersonalUsage` is also required when creating an `enrollmentToken`

Making these changes fixed the issue.